# Sorry for my laugh

Tags: grammar

What would be a right context corresponding to each meaning below?

> 1. Sorry for my laugh.
> 2. Sorry for my laughs.
> 3. Sorry for my laughing.

Comment: +1. I'm still thinking of contexts. But what I can come up quickly with is singular 'laugh', plural 'laughs' (for various occasions as 'laugh' is countable), and 'laughing' to denote some recent or ongoing activity.

Comment: I'd go for _sorry for laughing_. It clearly implies that it was the speaker that laughed, so you don't need to stress the possessive with _my_.

Comment: what if the speaker is referring to the past event and want to precisely say that he was sorry for his laughs, forget others. @oerkelens (and welcome back!)

Comment: Then he would have to specify which "laughs" he means.  Most likely, this would take the form of "[I'm] sorry {for laughing/[that] I laughed} _when you {said x/did y}._"

Comment: Actually, even in case of a past event, my version works. "Sorry for laughing when you told me your green-striped orange hay beetle had died." (And thanks :) I've been a bit busy lately, but I was never really gone :P )

Comment: Actually, if it is not _laughing_ I want to apologize for, you would do the same thing: _sorry for killing your beetle_. You wouldn't (or shouldn't) usually try to use a noun there: _sorry for my beetle kill_ (very awkward) although possible, quite formally, you could say _sorry for my killing your beetle_. _Sorry for killing your beetle_ is more usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@starsplusplus said:

> I might be able to come up with one or two, but they would be pretty contrived.

@Joe Kim said:

> If you don't mind, even if they won't be natural, can you give the examples for the other two, so that I can sense what is going on with the others. Thanks.

**Sorry for my laugh.** I have a throat injury. It makes my voice sound strange, and it makes my laugh sound like water gurgling down the drain.

---

I recorded sounds for your video game character. I made a few grunting sounds for when the character jumps, and I think those sound great. I also made a few humming sounds for when the character is talking, and those sound OK. The laughing sounds I recorded didn't come out as well as I wanted, and maybe you can't use those files. **Sorry for my laughs.**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. Or, at least, I might be able to come up with one or two, but they would be pretty contrived.

In almost all situations, *Sorry for laughing* would sound much more natural than any of the sentences you gave.

For example:

1. > "Hi Bob, sorry for laughing at you in the meeting earlier. It wasn't appropriate."
2. > Joe and Bob walk down the street. Joe slips on a banana peel and lands awkwardly. Bob laughs, then when it is clear his friend is in pain, he says:
   >   "Are you okay? Sorry for laughing, it's just you looked really funny!"
3. > "Sorry for laughing when you told me about your adventures, Alice."

Alternatively, particularly if you are talking about a past event or are going to supply more context, you could say *Sorry that I laughed*.

e.g.

- Sorry that I laughed when you told me your grandma died
- Sorry that I laughed during your speech. I thought you were making a joke.
- Sorry that I laughed at you on Friday. I didn't realise you were feeling so scared.

etc.

Comment: If you don't mind, even if they won't be natural, can you give the examples for the other two, so that I can sense what is going on with the others. Thanks.